# access denied to heroku app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, koding

I just created a ruby on rails 4 app in the `Koding` terminal Chrome App.  I successfully pushed the application with `git` to Heroku, but whenever I try and access the domain for my app, `<myapp>.herokuapp.com` I get a page that says:

```
Application Error
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.
```

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.

When I look at the `http://s3.amazonaws.com/heroku_pages/error.html/` logs it says:

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>DA3A6B32D49C510F</RequestId>
<HostId>1GLJkU8UYRWbwRD/P0rquzPhTnLOwUeRL37HBveDCKVjEY3yqc9GUtW84ivmx57l</HostId>
</Error>
```

I'm new to releasing apps on heroku, and any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Run `heroku logs --tail -a <myapp>` in the terminal, which shows you the streaming logs for your app. That should give you a load more information about what's going wrong.

Comment: Was just about to ask about the logs - have you got any info on the Heroku logs for us?

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in your production environment. 
To try it in your local machine, 
run:

rails s RAILS_ENV=production